# ASP.Net Core - Calculate bytes sent in download request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If a user starts a download for a fairly large file (500mb) but cancels the request prematurely how can I calculate the number of bytes that actually made it to the user?

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
    {
        IActionResult result = BadRequest();
        var path = Path.Combine(firstPart, secondPart);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);
            await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            result = Ok();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about what protocol is used, what class is `Response` (I guess some `WebResponse`-descendant), and where you catch the case a user cancelled the download?

Comment: The download is a "get" request. "Response" is of type HttpResponse. The download is cancelled when a user clicks the default cancel button in Chrome.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not...

Answer (score -2):

Validate this with JavaScript and send your file via AJAX. This way you're sure that it never even reaches your controller if the file is too big. I've experimented with Dropzone.js which did this for you.

Comment: I cannot use javascript or run anything on the client. Solution needs to be added inside the "download" action above.